# Resultant of two polynomials - generating matrix

Tags: matrices, polynomials, resultant

Calculate the resultant of x^2+1, x^2+3x

I know the resultant is the determinant of the matrix below but don't understand how that matrix is generated. Could someone please explain?

1 0 0 0
0 1 3 0
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant

Comment: You have an error : the first line should be 1 3 0 0